# Define an alias for a controller property in the view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have a `PersonController` that has the property `person`. The person itself has the properties `firstName`, `lastName`, etc.

When I access them in the view i always have to write:

```
<h:outputText value="#{personController.person.firstName}"/>
[...]
```

To simplify i created an "alias" via

```
<c:set var="p" value="#{personController.person}"/>
```

and now I can write

```
<h:outputText value="#{p.firstName}"/>
```

[Here](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#N1057A) is written that you should *avoid c:set if possible*.

Question 1: Why should I avoid it?

Question 2: What is the alternative for my "problem"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There the [`<ui:param>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/param.html) can be used for.

```html
<ui:param name="p" value="#{personController.person}" />
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) (explains when to (not) use JSTL in Facelets)